# Populating a Range parameter to array using a string variable

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string, range

I'm trying to select a row from a changed cell in that row and then populate an array from the selected row values.

When I try to build a string variable containing the selected row like Copyrange = Start Position & End Position and then feed that to the Range parameter into an array, it throws a subscript out of range error.

I need to formulate the correct row to assign to the Range, how can I do this if you can't pass a string variable into the Range parameter?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r, s As Long
  
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("PrioritySelect")) Is Nothing Then
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("PrioritySelect")) = "Select" Then
        r = Target.Row
        s = r + 8
        ' MsgBox "row " & r, , "Amended Cell..."
        
        Dim MyArray() As Variant
        
        'unallocated array
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim ThisWs As Worksheet
        Dim Copyrange As String
        Dim Position As String
        
        
        Set ThisWs = Worksheets("PIPPR")
        Position = "B" & r
        EndPosition = "B" & s
           MsgBox Position
            MsgBox EndPosition
            
        Let Copyrange = Position & ":" & EndPosition
        MsgBox Copyrange
                    
        MyArray = ThisWs.Range(Copyrange).Value2
        
        MsgBox "Lower Bound = " & LBound(MyArray)
        MsgBox "Upper Bound = " & UBound(MyArray)
        MsgBox MyArray(1)
        
        'MsgBox MyArray(1)
        
        
            ' Print student marks from the array to the Immediate Window
    Debug.Print "Values"
    For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        Debug.Print MyArray(i)
    Next i
```

Comment: Try using `Copyrange = Position & ":" & EndPosition` instead of `Let Copyrange = Position & ":" & EndPosition`. A string must receive a value in this simple way.

Comment: `ThisWs.Range(Copyrange)` cannot give a subscript out of range error. The place you get it is `MyArray(1)`. `MyArray` is a 2D array, not 1D.

Answer (score 0):

MyArray is a 2-dimensions array. You have to use it properly. Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r, s As Long
  
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("PrioritySelect")) Is Nothing Then
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("PrioritySelect")) = "Select" Then
        r = Target.Row
        s = r + 8
        ' MsgBox "row " & r, , "Amended Cell..."
        
        Dim MyArray() As Variant
        
        'unallocated array
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim ThisWs As Worksheet
        Dim Copyrange As String
        Dim Position As String
        
        Set ThisWs = Worksheets("PIPPR")
        Position = "B" & r
        EndPosition = "B" & s
           MsgBox Position
            MsgBox EndPosition
            
        Let Copyrange = Position & ":" & EndPosition
        MsgBox Copyrange
                            
        MyArray = ThisWs.Range(Copyrange).Value2
        
        MsgBox "Lower Bound = " & LBound(MyArray)
        MsgBox "Upper Bound = " & UBound(MyArray)
        MsgBox MyArray(1, 1)
        
        'MsgBox MyArray(1)
        
        
            ' Print student marks from the array to the Immediate Window
    Debug.Print "Values"
    For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        Debug.Print MyArray(i, 1)
    Next i
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This one use a one dimensional MyArray with strings instead or variant:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r, s As Long
  
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("PrioritySelect")) Is Nothing Then
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("PrioritySelect")) = "Select" Then
        r = Target.Row
        s = r + 8
        ' MsgBox "row " & r, , "Amended Cell..."
        
        'unallocated array
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim ThisWs As Worksheet
        Dim Copyrange As String
        Dim Position As String
        Dim Cell As Range
        Dim MyArray() As String
        
        Set ThisWs = Worksheets("PIPPR")
        Position = "B" & r
        EndPosition = "B" & s
           MsgBox Position
            MsgBox EndPosition
            
        Let Copyrange = Position & ":" & EndPosition
        MsgBox Copyrange
        
        ReDim MyArray(1 To ThisWs.Range(Copyrange).Cells.Count)
        i = 1
        For Each Cell In ThisWs.Range(Copyrange)
            MyArray(i) = Cell.Value2
            i = i + 1
        Next
        
        MsgBox "Lower Bound = " & LBound(MyArray)
        MsgBox "Upper Bound = " & UBound(MyArray)
        MsgBox MyArray(1)
        
        'MsgBox MyArray(1)
        
        
            ' Print student marks from the array to the Immediate Window
    Debug.Print "Values"
    For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        Debug.Print MyArray(i)
    Next i
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh that's so helpful, thanks Evil Blue Monkey! That works. Is there a way to feed it into a 1-dimensional array and therefore not have this problem?

Comment: I also can't seem to access the array values of i above 2 - the Debug.Print only prints out the first 2 values of the total of 9, which is odd.

Comment: @JamesintheUK Have a look at the [LBound() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/lbound-function) documentation and its `dimension` parameter

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the world's greatest programmer as you can all tell. The bit where I'm stuck is I don't understand how the array is formed. The range I have successfully contains 9 values, but those 9 don't seem to result in 9 values created in the array, only 2? As far as I can tell.

Comment: I've added  to the answer an extra code that uses a one dimensional MyArray. I've also turned it to a string type instead of a variant; since we have only to copy cells' values, using variant should be unnecessary.

Comment: The Debug.Print returns me the whole list. Mind that if the range `ThisWs.Range(Copyrange)` contains empty cells, an empty row will be printed for each of those.

Comment: That works but still spits out the column values and not the row values. It's odd because your code does use the Copyrange value which does appear to be a row range.

Comment: Oh heck, don't worry, I've just realised I am not building Copyrange correctly! Many thanks for all the help, much appreciated.

Comment: If the problem has been solved, you may mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks, how do I do that please? I can't see a button for Marking it as Answered?

Comment: There should be a button shaped as a "v" on the left side of the top corner of the answer. It's between the down-pointing button triangle and the clock-like button.